# how to avoid background for an image which is selected from photo gallery or captured from Camera in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, crop

[image]

I need to get only the selected image without background , we are trying to avoid the back ground and we need selected part should only cropped. and how to change the pixel data on tap selection of image color.

OR can we do like this:

Before crop:

[image]

After crop:

[image]

Comment: You have to search for the cropping library, can't get directly like that.

Comment: are you going to select this manually ?

Comment: Yes i am going to select that image manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow user to draw on image after selection using bezierpath, 
once you have path - You can use a shapeLayer for that. Something like:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer]; 

shapeLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;

[view.layer setMask:shapeLayer];//or make it as

[imageview.layer setMask:shapreLayer]; 

// and add imageView as subview  of whichever view you want. 
// draw the original image on the imageview in that case
```

To get it as an image,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layerrenderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```